# postgresql convert jsonb to set of records

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

Having issue with transforming jsonb to desired table type, any help would be appreciated.

**My jsonb is:**

```
{"left": ["ICMB", "IPERIOD", "IADDR", "KV"]}
```

I want ot transform it to:

```
position   element
left       ICMB
left       IPERIOD
left       IADDR
left       KV
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`jsonb_each()` and `jsonb_array_elements_text()`:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html)

```
with my_data(j) as (
values
('{"left": ["ICMB", "IPERIOD", "IADDR", "KV"]}'::jsonb)
)

select key as position, element
from my_data,
lateral jsonb_each(j) as each(key, val),
lateral jsonb_array_elements_text(j->key) as element;

 position | element 
----------+---------
 left     | ICMB
 left     | IPERIOD
 left     | IADDR
 left     | KV
(4 rows)
```